# Generic of Generics ? class A<T<U>>?

Tags: swift, class, generics, nested-generics

Can I somehow force the generic type to have a generic type ?
I want to have some functions, that have as a parameter type U, so how can I do that ?

Code:

```
class TableViewViewModel<T<U>> {
    typealias SectionDataType = T
    typealias RowDataType = U

    var sections = [SectionDataType<RowDataType>]()
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but that is just ugly, and error prone. E.g.
``ConcreteViewModel<Section<Model>, Model>``. It's just ugly. And I'm not talking about, that I am allowing ``ConcreteViewModel<Section<T>, U>`` where ``T and U`` are not the same, which is not what I want

Comment: Can I somehow force it with ``where`` clause ?

Comment: What use would a some-unknown type with a single unknown generic placeholder (`T<U>`) serve? I somewhat doubt you have some logic which is universal across only types with single generic placeholders. Almost certainly you're looking for a protocol (but without seeing a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to say for sure).

Comment: For example:    `class TableViewViewModel<T, U>
        where T : SectionDataType<U>
        where U : RowDataType`

Comment: Another example:  `class TableViewViewModel<T>
        where T : SectionDataType<RowDataType>`

Comment: Oops! I'm answering in C#!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring a protocol `SectionDataType` that requires an associated type. This means that any conforming type (like `Section` below) must implement a typealias. Then, in `TableViewViewModel` you can access the type which you were calling `U` through that typealias.

```
protocol SectionDataType {
    associatedtype RowDataType
}

struct Section<U>: SectionDataType {
    typealias RowDataType = U
}

class TableViewViewModel<T: SectionDataType> {
    typealias RowDataType = T.RowDataType

    var sections = [T]()
}
```

Comment: Really smooth. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do with a generic, is declare the types (what you are doing with the angle brackets). After that, it's syntax-as-usual. I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, so I'll just post an example. The following function declares three generic types (T, U, Z), takes a type U and a function as parameters, the function itself takes a value of type U and returns a value of type T. All of this returns a value of type Z. (This is a pretty useless func as-is, but an example of how to use generics in a complex fashion):

```
func myFunc<U,T,Z>(curry : (U) -> T, value : U) -> Z {
    return curry(value) as! Z
}
```